# I want make real time load using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, rest, vue.js, axios, restdb

I want to retrieve my added new Quote without need of page reload. Now I have to refresh page, then I will be able to see data. I am using restdb.io as a database, so after making post request, how can I retrieve all data without page reload, could you please give some advice, maybe try something else

Emitted method

```
methods: {
     addQuote(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.text.length === 0) {
            alert("Поле пустое. Пожалуйста введите цитату");
            return;
        }
        const newQuote = this.text;
        this.$emit("add-quote", newQuote);
        this.text = "";
    }
}
```

POST request

```
addQuote(quote) {
    if (this.quotes.length === 10) {
        alert("Для добавления новых цитат удалите одну из добавленных");
        return;
    }
    axios
        .post(
            "https://beeline-3fee.restdb.io/rest/db?apikey=<api_key>",
            { text: quote }
        )
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then(quote => {
            console.log("Success:", quote);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    }
}
```

GET request

```
mounted() {
    axios
    .get(
        "https://beeline-3fee.restdb.io/rest/db?apikey=<api_key>"
    )
    .then(response => (this.quotes = response.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid showing your apiKeys when you post publicly. you can use `apikey=<api_key>`, people will understand that is a placeholder for the real apiKey

Comment: you mean, like this example: https://codepen.io/balexandre/pen/XWmeJvm?editors=1010

Comment: @balexandre Yes, exactly thank you, its working but any idea how can I make instant, cause its taking probably 1-2 seconds

Comment: @SimoD'loMafuxwana note it thank you, i am just beginner, good advice!

Comment: you want instant, yes, it's very easy ... instead of getting the quotes again and again, just add it... like `this.quotes.unshift({text: this.quote})` ... I've now changed that in the example, so you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a `getQuotes` method and use it to load the quotes in `mounted` and to fetch all the quotes *after* you add a new quote

```
  mounted() {
    this.getQuotes();
  },
  methods: {
    getQuotes() {
      axios.get("https://beeline-3fee.restdb.io/rest/db?apikey=5eaaf516161b39295cdee783")
        .then((response) => (this.quotes = response.data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    },
    addQuote(quote) {
      if (this.quotes.length === 10) {
        alert("Для добавления новых цитат удалите одну из добавленных");
        return;
      }
      axios
        .post("https://beeline-3fee.restdb.io/rest/db?apikey=5eaaf516161b39295cdee783",
          {
            text: quote,
          }
        )
        .then((quote) => {
          console.log("Success:", quote);

          // this will fetch the quotes again
          this.getQuotes();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your help it is working, I will mark you as a solution, please give some advice, how can I make this process instant, its taking like 2-3 seconds to reload data

Comment: you can add `this.quotes.push(quote)` after the if statement and before the axios line, however you _might have to_ add more logic to remove the new quote *if* the add api call fails.